# XSLT - Copy element which has maximum attribute value than other elements in list

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to write XSl for the below input xml - Expected output should have the cluster element which has the maximum attribute (key)'s value.

Input:

```
<ProductList>
<Product ProductId="123">
 <ClusterList>
 <Cluster Key="1" Price="100.00"/>
 <Cluster Key="3" Price="200.00"/>
 <Cluster Key="2" Price="300.00"/>
 </ClusterList>
</Product>
<Product ProductId="456">
 <ClusterList>
 <Cluster Key="11" Price="100.00"/>
 <Cluster Key="33" Price="200.00"/>
 <Cluster Key="22" Price="300.00"/>
 </ClusterList>
</Product>
<ProductList>
```

Expected Output:

```
<ProductList>
<Product ProductId="123">
 <ClusterList>
 <Cluster Key="3" Price="200.00"/>
 </ClusterList>
</Product>
<Product ProductId="456">
 <ClusterList>
 <Cluster Key="33" Price="200.00"/>
 </ClusterList>
</Product>
<ProductList>
```

And here is the XSL which i have written, but not working :(

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/ClusterList/Cluster">
      <xsl:variable name="Max">
         <xsl:value-of select="/ClusterList/Cluster[not(preceding-sibling::Cluster/@Key &gt;= @Key) and not(following-sibling::Cluster/@Key &gt; @Key)]/@Key" />
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:if test="@Key=$Max">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **1.** Which XSLT processor are you using? **2.** What should be the result in case of tie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ClusterList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Cluster">
            <xsl:sort select="@Key" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor that does not support the EXSLT `math:max()` or `math:highest()` extension functions.

Note that in case of tie, only the first result will be returned.

---

To do it the way you have started, you would need to have:

```
<xsl:template match="Cluster">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::Cluster/@Key &gt; current()/@Key) and not(following-sibling::Cluster/@Key &gt; current()/@Key)">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

which is very inefficient, as it has to compare every `Cluster` to all its siblings anew.

Comment: Thanks Michael! You saved my day :)